# URL links opened from Facebook messenger won't open in my android app? (SMS, Chrome, and Gmail DO open in app)

Tags: android, kotlin, facebook, deep-linking

I added a share functionality in my android app that allows users to share a URL with other users. If a user opens the link on the device and taps on the URL link AND has my app installed then my app will open the content natively rather than in an external browser. This works flawlessly with all apps such as SMS, Teams, Chrome and gmail, however when a user opens the URL link from Facebook messenger it always opens in the external browser and never in app.

I also have the same functionality in my iOS application and have the same issue with any links opened from FB Messenger.

**Android Manifest**

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="somedomain.domain.com"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```

**MainActivity**

```
        ...code to read intent in OnCreate
        if (intent != null && intent.data != null) {
        val data = intent.data
        val host = data?.host

        // Parse INTENT and URL Data and open URL content in App.    
        val intent = Intent(this, SomeActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("data", data)
        intent.putExtra("standAlone", true)
        this.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: There is no requirement for any app to launch deeplinks into another app. You will get the same behavior by default with Firefox Fennec and Samsung Internet browsers.